# SQL/MySQL - How to implement AND clause in one-to-many relationship?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm sure this is a common problem but I can't seem to think of an answer.

If I have a table with a one-to-many relationship, how do I implement a query where all of the specified items from the "many" side of the relationship have to be met in order to return the record?

For example

```
Person               Person_Feature               Feature

PersonID Name        PersonID  FeatureID          FeatureID  Description
1        Dave        1         1                  1          Tall
2        Bill        1         2                  2          Black
                     1         3                  3          Male
                     2         1                  4          White
                     2         4                                  
                     2         3
```

If I were allowing a user to choose from features in the Feature table, how would I write a query that would only return a person that had **all** of the features chosen, however few or many that may be?

So a search for a tall, black, male would return Dave and not Bill, but a search for a tall male would return both.

Comment: Surely this is a many to many relationship?

Comment: @SEBBINFIELD You are correct, my mistake!

Answer (score 1):

This one should work:

```
SELECT P.Name
FROM Person P
  JOIN Person_Feature PF
    ON P.PersonID = PF.PersonID
  JOIN Feature F 
    ON PF.FeatureID = F.FeatureID
WHERE F.Description IN ('Tall','Black')
GROUP BY P.PersonID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Basically I'm selecting all those who have the given search criteria and group people by ID. Then i filter them by the COUNT. If there are 2 criteria, that means that there should be exactly 2 rows (if there are 3, the `COUNT(*)` should be 3). If the count is less than the number of criteria, then it means that the person doesn't match all the criteria (but only some).

Comment: That's ingeniously simple, thank you. It looks like it would work but I'll give it a try and mark you as the answer if it's all ok.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT P.Name
FROM Person P
JOIN Person_Feature PF ON P.PersonID = PF.PersonID
JOIN Feature F ON PF.FeatureID = F.FeatureID
WHERE F.Description in ('Tall','Black');
```

If this is not the correct understanding of your requirement, please elaborate more so that I can enhance the query.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, Neels, but I think this would produce an "OR" query, returning anyone who was tall OR black. I would like to ensure that both features are matched.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT P.Name
FROM Person P
JOIN Person_Feature PF ON P.PersonID = PF.PersonID
JOIN Feature F ON PF.FeatureID = F.FeatureID
WHERE F.Description IN ('Tall','Black')
GROUP BY P.PersonID 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT F.Description) = SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT G.Description) 
FROM G.Feature WHERE G.Description IN ('Tall','Black');
```

This is not a tested code. Kindly excuse for any syntax error. Consider it as a pseudo code